# Anyone had experience with or know of the Tascam BB 1000 CD?

Tags: cd

Hey so I have a on set recording job in April and the producer has already hired the equipment for me to get comfortable with and it is the Tascam BB 1000 CD, having briefly looked through the user manual I have been given the impression that it only records 44.1 KHz
and 16 bit where I'm sure the industry standard is 48k and 24 bit?My question is that has anybody used this model and know any different?

Below is link to show you the model
[Tascam BB 1000 CD][1]

[1]: http:// http://tascam.com/product/bb-1000cd/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it looks very music oriented and a bit of a Swiss army knife for the budding musician. It has features you don't need and it seems to lack others you could need, like 48k/24b recording or a limiter. The specifications section does not even address sample and bit rates. It runs off 8 AA batteries which may be a bit of a pain depending on how long it lasts on one set of these (if you end up using 3 8-AA-battery-sets on set, that's 24 AA batteries, that's a damn lot of AA batteries)... Finally, I haven't even investigated the preamps.

If I were you, I'd ask him if it would be fine to change recorder. If he says no, I'd buy one (or get lent one?) like an H4n or a DR-100 which would make my time on the shoot worth something more.

EDIT: according to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRfyLRyrhls, there is a built-in limiter. I keep thinking it's not adapted to what we do, simply from the lack of 48/24.

Comment: The mic pres are probably the same as what they use in everything else, but you're right - 44.1/16 just isn't good enough.  Shame, it's very cheap.  Would be nice to have as a spare recorder. 